# CodeIgniter default page on remote server

Tags: codeigniter

I'm relatively new to CI and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to set the default page of CI. I just transferred my files from my local server to my remote server and am having some problems. Firstly, I think it's important to note that I edited the .htaccess file so that the index.php was removed from the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Secondly, in my `config.php` file, I have:

```php
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'sportstream';
```

`sportstream` is the name of a controller that is found in the `application/controllers/` folder. From my experiences without using CI (or any other framework), the `index.php` file inside of the `public_html` folder on the remote server is the one that is loaded by default upon visiting a site. But, with CI, whenever I try to visit my domain name, a 404 error is returned. I have tried setting to `base_url` to http://www.mysite.com without any luck.

Does anyone here know how to make it so that upon visiting http://www.mysite.com that http://www.mysite.com/sportstream will be loaded?

Comment: We need more detail for being able to help, show necessary parts of `sportstream.php`, `config.php`, `routes.php` files.

Comment: I'll give whoever is interested ssh access to my remote server so that can search around to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `RewriteBase` in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**NOTE:** I have added a `?` after the `index.php` as well.

I would also set the follow to an empty string (after you have tried the above):

```php
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Finally, in your `routes.php` file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'sportstream';
```

### Update

In `application/config/database.php` you need to change your database driver. On your localhost, MySQLi was the database driver set. On your remote server, however, MySQLi was not installed, so changing it to MySQL should fix the issue.

```
//old - works on local server
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

//new - works on remote server
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

For some reason, Codeigniter just "breaks" and shows the blank screen with no errors.

Comment: I'd be willing to give you ssh access to my remote server if that will help you solve the problem.

Comment: what is your email? I don't want to share my ssh login credential on a public forum like this.

Comment: Regarding update part of answer: you should install on your server at least php-mysqli because php-mysql has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and will be removed in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default controller in `$route['default_controller'] ="sportstream";` it is located in aplication/config/route.php`, So when visiting`http://www.mysite.com/`the`sportstream` controller will be loaded by default.

Check about default controller in [User guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Switch back the `$config['index_page'] = '';`

If you renamed the `index.php` then you must enter the `index_page` name in `config`  or else you can keep it blank.

Recommended Codeigniter starter guide: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-basics/

Comment: Doing this gets rid of the 404 header, but it just shows a blank page instead.

Comment: Create a view and load the view in `sportstream`. @lance

Comment: In the sportstream class, I have $this->load->view('header', $header);
   $this->template->load('main', null, $data);
   $this->load->view('footer');

Comment: So, two views and one template are being loaded.

Comment: Did the templates have content in it.

Comment: Any other suggestions?